# How to find $g^2(x)$ from $f^{-1}g(x)$ and $g(f(x))$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Given that $f^{-1}g(x)=3x-2$ and $gf(x)=12x-8$. Find $g^2(x)$.

Can anyone give me some hints on this question?

Comment: Is the problem above stated exactly as it is in a book? Might you not mean this: " Given that $f^{-1}(g(x))=3x-2 $ and $g(f(x))=12x-8$, find $(g(x))^2$ "? This is a high school precalculus problem, isn't it?

Comment: I have voted down both your question (for reason in my comment above) and the answer (for reason explained in several of my comments below). I need clarification about the intent of the problem. Does $f^{-1}g(x)$ mean $f^{-1}(x)$ TIMES $g(x)$? Or does it mean $f^{-1}$ OF $g(x)$? same question about $gf$ in second equation. And does the problem want $g(g(x))$ or $g(x)g(x)$?

Comment: @DSlomer64 What does precalculus mean? Are the branches of mathematics linearly ordered or just calculus can be compared with _all_ other fields as an _before/after_? I am sincerely curious. I have seen the name in many places and I have always wondered what is the meaning of "precalculus."

Comment: Precalculus should NOT be thought of as "Algebra III". Strictly speaking, it SHOULD NOT contain any calculus, but most precalculus books contain limits and derivatives. In a sense, *limit* is precalculus, since without it, there's no calculus--i.e., everything in calculus is derived from some limit or other. If included in a text, IMHO, it should be in an appendix. There's no sense rushing through the precalculus topics just to get a head start on calculus. (continued in next comment)

Comment: (continuation) What topics? A thorough understanding of functions and their inverses, especially the transcendental; sequences and series beyond arithmetic and geometric progressions; parametrically-defined, polar, and vector functions, preferably in a unified manner: and all sorts of applications of as of the above. Do that properly and students will be ready for AB, BC, and college calculus. And there will be no time for calculus. BTW, limits should be studied when needed, e.g., series. And related average rates of change easily transfer in calculus to instantaneous.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

HINT

$gf(f^{-1}g(x))= g(f(f^{-1}(g(x))))=g(id(g(x)))=g(g(x))=g^2(x)$

Comment: I'm confused by the answer and all the upvotes. 

If $g(x) = \sin(x)$, then surely $g^2(x) = \sin^2(x) = (\sin(x))^2$, not $\sin(\sin(x))$. It's a precalculus problem.

Also, surely $fg$ is the function resulting from the multiplication $f(x)g(x)$. It doesn't say $f(g(x))$. It's precalculus. High school.

Comment: I'll go along with this:

$g(f(f^-1(g(x)))=g(g(x))$

But there are missing/assumed parentheses in answer (and probably question) that seems to border on slop to me.

Comment: Function composition is precalculus ... and taught in high school. Also, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition to see how the composition symbol is sometimes dropped, and how $f^2(x)$ is short for $f(f(x))$

Comment: @DSlomer64 In the Answer I have tried to add those parentheses for clarity.

Comment: @Bram28--I don't doubt what you say in your first comment, but surely no competent high school precalculus teacher--me, for one--would use the exponent "2" to mean anything but "squared". Moreover, every high school precalculus book I've ever seen has used $fg$ in the context $fg(x)$ to mean $f(x)g(x)$. Besides, parentheses are important. If omitted in question, how do you know where to put them.

Comment: Correction to my previous comment: $fg(x)$ should be $(fg)(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

The high school precalculus world makes the following definitions:

$f^{-1}$ is the function that is the inverse of the one-to-one function $f$.

$fg$ (also written $f\times g$, but with a dot instead of $\times$) is defined to be the function named $(fg)$, so that function $(fg)(x)=f(x)g(x)$.

$(f\circ g)$ is defined to be the function named $(f\circ g)$, so that the function $(f\circ g)(x)$ = $f(g(x))$.

$f^n(x)=(f(x))^n, n\ne-1.$

With these standard high school calculus definitions in mind, it seems reasonable to assume that the previous Answer is flawed, making assumptions not necessarily valid in the OP's problem--i.e., maybe OP omitted some parentheses and @Bram is just trying to help.

Parentheses make all the difference. Is it multiplication or composition where two function names are adjacent (in two places)? Is the 2 an exponent or does it imply $g\circ g$?

I assume the problem wants an algebraic answer in terms of $x$ alone. I think any posted Answer should be preceded by having acquired such an answer.

I've been working on this for long enough to know that I need clarification. There are at least four possible problems to work, with and without parentheses where legal or omitted as in given problem statement.

BTW, as written and interpreting it in terms of the above definitions, the problem becomes:

Given $f^{-1}(x)g(x)=3x-2$ and $g(x)f(x)=12x-8$. Find $(g(x))^2$.

I sincerely doubt that's the precise problem statement or is equivalent to it. Surely the first equation should begin $f^{-1}(g(x))$.

Comment: "The high school precalculus world makes the following definitions":  I think the answer should strike a note of caution on this point, as the world of high school precalculus is very broad, and the galaxy of syllabuses and textbooks do not all follow the definitions given. Some do. Others not. In my country, every high school syllabus I'm aware of uses the notation of the other answer - but websites and imported textbooks can easily be found that follow this answer, too. Following a particular convention may reflect local educational custom rather than pedagogical competence or convenience

Comment: Look, I just want the problem in question to be stated without any chance of ambiguity. OP hasn't replied with any changes, so I have also lost interest in this Question and Answers.

Comment: So how does the "exponent-two-means-composition" world write "the square of sin(x) if not $ sin^2(x)$? It has to be either the awkward $(sin(x))^2$ or the ambiguous-looking $sin(x)^2$.

Comment: The trig functions are an interesting exception - but then, it's fairly rare to compose the sine function with itself, since for practical purposes, once you have applied a trig function to an angle, you now have a trigonometric ratio rather than an angle you'd want to apply another trig function to. I've seen pre-calc textbooks introduce the $\sin^2 x$ notation with the explicit warning that this notation is not in line with notation elsewhere in the book - often accompanied by the note that $\sin^{-1} x$ *does* have the usual meaning, and is not $\frac{1}{\sin x}$

Comment: Which textbook[s]?

Comment: It's the standard notation in British A-level textbooks - and indeed exams!